# 500 Internal Server Error in php website

Tags: php, .htaccess, internal-server-error

A web application built in php is showing 500- Internal Server Error. I am able to login to the website's admin panel, but upon accessing a service in the website, no response is given back. With the help of REST Client, I found out that webservice is returning an Internal Server Error with code-500. It was working perfectly till two days before.

I found one entry in .htaccess file. This is it.

```
# Use PHP54.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

What could be the problem?

PS:

Along with .htaccess file,  I saw two files with names `.htaccess_sucuribackup.1345692508` what are they? Never saw them anything like that before.

Comment: can you please paste your .htaccess code in question. It is because of some .htacess improper code.

Comment: I have already posted it. Please have a look at it. @Helping Hands

Comment: That is just 2 lines which is not enough..

Comment: There was only 2 lines in the file. @Helping Hands

Comment: please change those to this AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

Comment: The Sucuri backup looks like your web hosting provider ran a scan and was flagging your .htaccess for some reason, at least I think. I suggest contacting your web hosting provider on that one.

As for the AddHandler, that's sometimes necessary on some web hosting providers.

As for the error code 500, I usually find my Apache error log and tail it out while running the code in order to see what's causing that Apache error code 500. For instance `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: How can I access server error log? @Volomike

Comment: Is there a space between 5 & . ???@Karthick Kumar Ganesh

Comment: Is there a space between 4 & .  in AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php ??? @Volomike

Comment: @WD To access your server error log, contact your web hosting provider on that one -- it's different per your hosting plan. You can also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors','On');` to try and see all errors, but note that this shows also warnings too, like undeclared variables, which are not errors, but not recommended programming technique.

Comment: A 500 Error is often caused due to an issue with Permissions.

Comment: @WD Is there a space? Yes. Here's [the info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) on that. The code sets the MIME handler for files ending in the .php extension to be loaded by whatever the web server is processing for application/x-httpd-php54 MIME type.

Comment: @WD Luzan makes a good point -- sometimes you have to chown a file on the web server to have the proper ownership. For instance, on Ubuntu Linux web servers, I have to do `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` in order for all my pages to load properly. However, it's different per hosting plan, so you have to file a support ticket to ask what's recommended.